# install of ember-bootstrap 1.x hangs

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-bootstrap

ember-cli: 2.14.2
node: 8.4.0
os: win32 x64

For some reason, my npm installation of any ember-bootstrap 1.x version always hangs on fsevents.

```
C:\Users\rrush\Documents\GitHub\xxxxxxxxxxx>npm install
[            ......] | extract:fsevents: sill extract is-descriptor@0.1.6
```

I've tried several versions of ember-bootstrap 1.x, node and ember(-cli). They always hang up on fsevents installation.

Any 0.x version will install just fine though.

From what I've gathered, fsevents is only meant to be installed on Mac, not on a Windows machine. Is there any way to circumvent the (trying to) install of fsevents ? I did npm install --no-optional, but to no avail...

**EDIT 1:** `npm install ember-bootstrap@1.0.0-rc.1 --verbose --no-optional` Out of all the 1.x options, this one seems to work.

Comment: What is the exact command you are typing? Is it `ember install ember-bootstrap`? Also, have you already figured it out?

Comment: It is, I have also tried npm install ember-bootstrap. Haven't figured it out yet, kinda gave up on it... I did notice that in a 0.x build, the fsevents package is properly flagged as optional and thus skipped.

Comment: Oh, and also tried with --no-optional. No luck.

Comment: That's ok. I just want to try and see if I can recreate it. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Tried it at work on 8.1. Same thing. So its not limited to OS or machine for that matter.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm having the same issue. That is bizare. Maybe see the open issues on Github?

Comment: I have opened an issue on github. I'll edit accordingly that I'm not the only one experiencing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue is located within npm, specifically on Windows machines. When you issue the download straight from github, it installs perfectly. The root cause is unknown so far.

simonihmig (creator) had the following to say:

> I was able to reproduce this on Windows 10 (in a VirtualBox). I don't
>   think the root issue is within ember-bootstrap, rather probably npm
>   itself (some dead locking issue or so), as I was able to "fix" this by
>   downgrading findup-sync (more a workaround, but worked for me). Here
>   is a PR: #435. Took me quite some time...
>
> npm i --save-dev kaliber5/ember-bootstrap#downgrade-findup

Link to this issue: [ember-bootstrap issue 430](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/issues/430)